# Notation and Quantifiers

Tags: notation, quantifiers, article-writing

I was wondering what is a *natural way* to write certain *formal* expressions, without make them look too cumbersome.

In particular, what I learned from various books is that, when we deal with the existential quantifier, we use the symbol "$:$" and then "$\wedge$" or simply a comma ",". Thus, for example, we have

- $ \exists x: P(x) \wedge Q(x)$,
- or $ \exists x: P(x), Q(x)$.

In particular, the last expression looks kinda better, because it uses the quantifier (and quantifiers are not yet considered too formal), but it does not use "$\wedge$", which should already look too *logical*.

Now, how do we write expressions with "$\forall$"?

In general, for what I have studied (e.g. Velleman's "How to prove it"), we should write something like
$$ \forall x \ ( \ P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x) \ ).$$

However, I do have the feeling that this is already considered a bit too cumbersome (I am referring in particular to the brackets), if – for example – we are using it to specify something about $x$ in a definition.

Thus, is –for example – $$ \forall x, \  \ P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x) \ $$ wrong?

I think so, but I don't know another option to write the same.

As always, any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various notations for [restricted (or bounded) quantifiers](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier).

You can use also :

> $(\forall x)_P Q(x)$

which is the abbreviation for : $\forall x(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$,

and :

> $(\exists x)_P Q(x)$

which abbreviates : $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.

---

For some suggestions, you can see :

- Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals : A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&pg=PA80) (2nd ed - 2011), **Ch.2.6 Writing Mathematics**, page 80-on,

and specifically the sub-sections [page 86] :

> 2.6.9. Distinguish Formal vs. Informal Writing
>
> 2.6.10. Miscellaneous Writing Tips.

Regarding *quantifiers*, see **Ch.1.5 Quantifiers**, page 34-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, my question does not concern other formal way of writing expressions with quantifiers. It is rather about how to write _informal_ expressions still using – partly – quantifiers.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for the references. However, now a very straightforward question arise. If you have an expression – not in the body of the text! (such as \begin{equation}, etc) – which of the two expressions I will write down do you choose?

Comment: 1. $X := \{ x \ | \ \forall X \in \wp (X) \ ( x \in X \ ) \ \}$

Comment: 2. $X := \{ x \ | \ \forall X \in \wp (X), \  x \in X \ \ \}$

Comment: To me, it seems the second is just wrong, but maybe the first is considered too cumbersome.

Comment: @Kolmin - **personally** I do not like the "comma" (,) in the formulae; I prefer the use of parentheses ...